# monit failed script no print out on stdout inside docker container

Tags: bash, docker, monit

I'm using monit inside docker container. While I setup

> check host dns with address 8.8.8.182
>
> if failed port 53 type udp protocol dns then exec "/bin/bash -c printf 'hello\n'"

when failed, there is no output on container console, also there is no output on container logs by `docker logs my_container`

Any idea ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: get a shell in the container  with `docker exec -it container_id bash`and then debug, launch monit, see what happens

Comment: launch the monit, no output, monit can detect that there is no DNS service on 8.8.8.182 by `monit summary`. But no other debug info.

Comment: why the down vote? really no idea?

Comment: Actually, the trigger is ok, monit successfully detects the no DNS service, only problem is the `exec` part, I can get like `/bin/touch /tmp/afile` working, but no stdout methods works, for example `printf` or `echo`

Comment: can you show you `docker run`command? PS: I did'nt downvote

Comment: `docker run -ti --name=monitest ubuntu /bin/bash` thx man

Comment: and `docker events`?

Comment: never checked `docker events`, will check it, thx man

Comment: I thought the problem is, because that the monit process is a daemon process. Totally no new idea ...

Comment: So try with `docker run -dt`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I created a io file, and output the info to that file with

`set logfile /var/run/mylogfile`

and read that file periodically.